How to Use MAUI Pop-Up in ViewModel Instead of XAML.cs (Page Code-Behind)?
I’m trying to implement a pop-up in my .NET MAUI project and want to trigger it from a ViewModel or a separate class, instead of the XAML.cs (code-behind) file.
I am able to show a pop-up using DisplayAlert when it’s implemented directly in the XAML.cs file, as shown in the official documentation:
MAUI Pop-Up Documentation- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups?view=net-maui-8.0.
However, when I attempt to implement it in the ViewModel, I get the following error:
The name 'DisplayAlert' does not exist in the current context
Here’s an example of what I am trying to do in my ViewModel:

My Questions:
How can I trigger a MAUI pop-up (like DisplayAlert) from my ViewModel?
Do I need to inject any services or interfaces to achieve this?
What’s the best practice for using pop-ups in a ViewModel in a .NET MAUI project?
I want to follow MVVM best practices, so I’d like to avoid putting logic in the code-behind file if possible. Any help or examples would be appreciated!

You may consider using Maui CommunityToolkit Popup.  You can then present a Popup in viewmodel.
